# Map Node doesn't exists while concatenating in Biztalk

Tags: mapping, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

Actually I m trying to concatenate values from two elemnts of source schema to destination schema. 
but the problem is that in some file i get the 2nd element which I am concatenating but in some I dont get. When I get it is working fine. 
 When I dont get the 2nd element no other Nodes are coming . So I want to handle both case. When 2nd node is not availbale in file then also it should display all other nodes. In

Comment: Do you use the BizTalk mapper or XSLT?

Comment: I Am using BizTalk Mapper

Answer (score 0):

You need to link both source elements through an Index Functoid.

This happens because optional source elements get wrapped in for-each loops in the XSLT so if one is missing, the code will not even run.

The Index Functoid shorcuts this.  You can see the result in the generated XSLT using Validate Map.